# UITextField cannot become first responder while animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

At the moment, I am creating a feature that animates a UITextfield from the bottom of the screen to a given point using a UIView animation block.

For some reason while the UITextfield animates upwards, it is unresponsive to touch events and will not become the first responder until after it calls completion.

I have created a sample project below to show the issue.

https://github.com/AdamBCo/Textfield-Animation-Issue

As you can see in the example, UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction is set in the UViewAnimation block.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by implementing the following solution:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if ([self.textField.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation])
    {
        [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

I have since updated the sample code online to show the animation of the presentation layer, the ending destination of the model layer, and a way to see if the clicks are inside of the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the intended action. What you are seeing is the CALayer animating therefore it won't respond to a touch until it's "landed". What you can do is add a touch recognizer then test your hit points to begin responding on a certain object. I have to ask though, what UI/UX scenario would this be good practice?

Comment: This was helpful to me in the scenario that I am animating the background color of the textfield to indicate it needs attention.  It actually made for bad UX that the user should have to wait for the animation (though brief) to fade.